# Sql Query Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Votes contain data

```
Votes    Designation    CandidateID
 4         President      Person1
 3         President      Person2
 5         Secretary      Person5
 1         Vice-Present   Person6
```

I want to query the winner candidate only per designation.
like

```
 4      President Person1
 5      Secretary Person2
 1      Vice_President Person6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good use for `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
select v.*
from (select v.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by designation order by votes desc) as seqnum
      from votes v
     ) v
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that this uses `dense_rank()`.  If there is a tie, then all "winners" are included.  You can use `row_number()` to choose an arbitrary winner.

***[See working SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae518/6/0)***